# Float bug in chrome? 1px extra padding, but it's not padding

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

The following html and css shows two divs inside a container. The left div isn't floated; the right div is floated right.

The right div  seems to be one pixel too narrow, and the red background color of the container is therefore showing through in that one pixel gap.

This is a simplification of my problem.  http://jsfiddle.net/XPd9J/

HTML

```
<div class="inner-wrapper">

    <div class="right-sidebar">
        &nbsp;
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        &nbsp;<br /><br />
    </div>

</div>​
```

CSS

```
.inner-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
    overflow:auto;
    width:90%;
    padding:0;
    margin:20px 0 0 20px;
}
.right-sidebar {
    position:relative;
    width:40% !important;
    background-color:lime;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.content {
    position :relative;
    width:60%;
    background-color:silver;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
​
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not the float that makes the problem. It's the percentage width. In FF and IE it works perfect, but Chrome calculates percentage width so, that not always the pixels sum up to the full 100%. Just try to slighty change the window width and you will notice the extra 1 px to disappear/appear sometimes.

How to avoid this behavior? You need to have use the same percentage somehow, so it is calculated just exactely the same. The right sidebar is 40% wide, so you need to have a right margin of 40% for the content div (these 40% are 40% of the containing block element)

http://jsfiddle.net/XPd9J/1/

```
.inner-wrapper {
    background-color:red;
    overflow:auto;
    width:90%;
    padding:0;
    margin:20px 0 0 20px;
}
.right-sidebar {
    width:40% !important;
    background-color:lime;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.content {
    background-color:silver;
    margin:0 40% 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks yunzen. Thanks for editting my markup too, :-) I'd vote for your answer if I knew how to :-)

Comment: Oops, ran out of my five minutes allotted time to edit. Try again.I'd found that adding style=margin:0;padding:0 to the body element had a positive effect in some circumstances. I'd also found that opera (and probably Safari, I still have to download that) have the same problem figuring out percentage widths of floated elements. But your solution is one of simple genius. I can't quite believe it works. I've tried different percentages and they all seem okay so far. I've searched the internet for this answer. Thanks once again!

Comment: @WotNot You can vote with a reputation of 15 min. But you can accept the anser. Click on the tick mark left from my answer and it will turn green.

Answer (score 7):

Another easy option to get the full 100% is to set the parent element to `overflow:hidden` and your element to `width:101%`.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered that issue and I use two option the `display:inline-table` and `display:table-cell` in the parent div of the floated elements..although it is not a table, I use that as an alternative

Comment: Dude!!! display:inline-table fixed it for me.  Any insight into why this one works?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this in the future, it's possible to create left sidebar / content / right sidebar with liquid floats using the above method. It might be done like this:

Container div

right-sidebar  width:30%;float:right;margin:0;padding:0;

content width:40%;float:right;margin:0;padding:0;

left-sidebar margin-right:70%;margin:0;padding:0;

End container div

Provided all the containers have margin:0;padding:0; then this works in FF, IE, Chrome, Safari and Opera (latest) without a problem. Genius. The dodgy browsers should have had  this problem solved a long time ago - one can only guess that web designers don't often need pixel perfect placement of sidebars otherwise there would have been huge pressure on the browser builders.

Comment: In fact, fluid layouts with percentages are very seldom compared to fixed width layout. These are easier to handle and often better looking. That's why the percentage bug persisted so long

Answer (score 0):

You got two non-breaking spaces there. &nbsp; character causes the 1px extra space on the left of the right sidebar. Btw, `position: relative` is redundant in this context (it's only useful when you have to fix something in IE6).

Comment: Thanks Gabriele Romanato, the &nbsp; weren't the problem, it seems to be be fixed now (see above)

Answer (score 0):

Set "inner-wrapper" to overflow hidden (just in case). Then on the right div use calc(40% + 1px) to fix the issue.